# Unsure of how to convert variables in batch

Tags: batch-file

I've been having some issues trying to convert the variables in this batch file from one to another.

```
echo Select One:
echo Variable One [1]
echo Variable Two [2]
echo Variable Three [3]
set /p var=
```

At this point the user would type in 1, 2, or 3 to continue. The code goes on to this.

```
set "1=Variable One"
set "2=Variable Two"
set "3=Variable Three"
echo %var%
```

I'm trying to echo out what was originally echo'd (i.e. "variable one", "variable two"), but it still displays "1", "2", and "3" to my screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "var1=One"
SET "var2=Two"
SET "var3=Three"
SET "input="
SET /p "input=Input 1,2 or 3 ? "
IF DEFINED var%input% CALL echo %%var%input%%%
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's one way to do something similar - but it's a trivial and artificial demonstration.

You *can* set a numeric as a variable, but natch syntax defines `%n` (where `n` is `0..9` as a parameter's value. To retrieve the *value* of variable, you use `%varname%` which would be for instance `%1%` - which batch will interpret as parameter #1 + a `%`, not the contents of variable `1`.
e
Solution : always begin a variablename with an alphabetic character (there are a few symbols, too)

The `CALL echo %%var%input%%%` is an advanced structure requiring an understanding of the parsing procedure, so I'll not confuse matters by trying to explain it.

Perhaps you should examine the `choice` instruction (at the prompt, type `choice /?` ) to make a selection from a list, menu-style.

It depends on what you really want to do - and the approach may depend on the application. Trivial examples can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to create a number as a variable when you say `SET 1=Variable One`. This is not legal as a variable name (what is left of the `=`) cannot be just a number.

I believe what you need is a simple `IF` statement:

```
:Menu
echo Select One:
echo Variable One [1]
echo Variable Two [2]
echo Variable Three [3]
set /p var=

REM Initialize selection.
SET "Selected="
IF "%var%"=="1" SET Selected=Variable One
IF "%var%"=="2" SET Selected=Variable Two
IF "%var%"=="3" SET Selected=Variable Three

REM Make sure a valid selection was made.
IF "%Selected%"=="" (
    ECHO Please enter a valid value.
    GOTO Menu
)

ECHO You selected: %Selected%
```

Comment: I would add some extra check after the IFs. You shouldn't get there, unless you typed in an incorrect choice, so an `echo` and a jump to end or back to the question would capture that situation.  Apart from that, this is exactly the way to do it.